# Weka data load error

Tags: weka

I want to load the data in [breast-cancer-wisconsin](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/) through Weka Explorer as a C4.5 data file and I'm getting the following errors when choosing both to load C4.5 .data and C4.5 .names: [image]
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not look like the [C45 names file](http://www.cs.washington.edu/dm/vfml/appendixes/c45.htm) is correct. Try replacing `breast-cancer-wisconsin.names` with this one:

```
2, 4.
clump: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
size: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
shape: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
adhesion: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
epithelial: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
nuclei: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
chromatin: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
nucleoli: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
mitoses: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
```

Note that class comes first (only labels).

Here I have removed the first column of subjects' id in the original dataset using

```
$ cut -d, -f2-11 breast-cancer-wisconsin.data > breast-cancer-wisconsin.data
```

but it is not difficult to adapt the above code.

Alternative solutions:

1. Generate a csv file: you just need to add a header to the `*.data` file and rename it as `*.csv`. E.g., replace `breast-cancer-wisconsin.data` with `breast-cancer-wisconsin.csv` which should look like

   ```
   clump,size,shape,adhesion,epithelial,nuclei,chromatin,nucleoli,mitoses,class
   5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
   5,4,4,5,7,10,3,2,1,2
   3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2
   6,8,8,1,3,4,3,7,1,2
   ...
   ```
2. Construct directly an `*.arff` file by hand; that's not really complicated as there are few variables. An example file can be found [here](http://cdhaenen.plil.fr/Ressources/Datamining/breast-cancer.arff).